Using past perfect continuous with past simple

I think that  I was working when she arrived means my work was still ongoing when she got to my place

I think that I had been working when she arrived means I could have stopped, e.g. 10 minutes before she arrived, but it is also possible that I was still working when she arrived

but what about I had been working for 2 hours when she arrived?  I think it may mean that I was either still working or had already finished dealing with it, but not, for example, 10 minutes earlier, but just a moment before she came in?



Yes, your interpretations are correct. (3) implies that you were still working and had started two hours earlier.

@Kate Bunting what about this "I had been working since the morning when she arrived". The same as 2 so either still ongoing or not or like 3 so still ongoing?

It's not a very natural sentence, and would require further context. "When she arrived at 4 p.m. I was tired because I had been working since morning" (could mean that you were still working) - or "I had been working since morning and had just stopped for a cup of tea".

@Kate Bunting wouldn't the same thing happen with "for"? ""When she arrived at 4 p.m. I was tired because I had been working for 2 hours" Could we then say that "for and since" imply that something was still ongoing if context doesn't say something different but the rest so for example no time expression or "all morning" without context are ambiguous either still happening or not?

Yes, you could put it that way.

I had been working since morning when she arrived. No "the" in that case.

The past perfect continuous  "I had been working for two hours" expresses that the two-hour mark was reached, no more, no less. When used with atelic verbs the past perfect continuous with that time expression does not entail any cessation of the act, although in combination with other things in the sentence it could support that meaning.

I had been reading for two hours when I came upon that passage.
I had been reading for two hours when the doorbell rang.

